# copying plist to document directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How do I copy an existing plist I have in the app build to the Document directory?

My plist is basically an array of dictionary, I have successfully copy the plist to the directory using the following:

```
 BOOL success;
            NSError *error;

            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"States.plist"];

            success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
            if (success) return;

            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"States" ofType:@"plist"];    
            success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:filePath error:&error];

            if (!success) {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy Plist. Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
```

However, when I try to access the NSDictionary it gives me:

```
CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

Why is this? I have to relaunch the app again and now I can change the dictionary stored in my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new pList in the documents directory, and set to the contents of the existing plist you have.

Comment: I wanted to copy it off first, as now I have it in my app bundle.. if you were to say create it first then how do I create it in the documents directory? Do it manually from the finder? What if it's on a phone?

Comment: Put an empty plist in your app bundle and then copy the existing plist there. If that doesn't work then you need to go over your design decisions. I can help you with that if you give me more information on what you want/need and implementation.

Comment: I want to be able to write it back again to the plist, and therefore that's why I am avoiding using app bundle.. i was thinking of copying the plist to the documents dir so that I can write it again there

Comment: Yeah that's what I said. Copy the plist in your documents directory... I can't help you further unless you provide me with more information.

Comment: look at my updated code above, that's the issue I am facing now.. it has to do with mutability.. the first time after copying the plist from app bundle to doc directory and load it into my NSMutableArray the dictionary stored for each array can't be mutated.. if I load the app again, it does it just fine

Comment: See http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/ - thats how you should do it to copy to documents dir and make it writable

Answer (score 6):

This is the way I copy the *.plist file to documents folder. Hope this helps.

```
+ (NSString*) getPlistPath:(NSString*) filename{
    //Search for standard documents using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    //First Param = Searching the documents directory
    //Second Param = Searching the Users directory and not the System
    //Expand any tildes and identify home directories.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
+ (void) copyPlistFileToDocument{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [Utilities getPlistPath:@"AppStatus.plist"];
    if( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath])
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppStatus" ofType:@"plist"];
            BOOL copyResult = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
            if(!copyResult)
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable plist file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```