# Adding new key/value of type string to pList

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, plist

I am trying to add programmatically new row to my pList file on iPhone. But I can't find out how.
I want to add key: someKey/ type: string/ someValue: string

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPlist" ofType:@"plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"someKey", @"someValue", nil];
[plist setObject:newArray forKey:@"someKey"];
[plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[plist release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify files in the application bundle, which is what your code above is attempting to do.

If the file is supposed to be modifiable, you need to move it into the documents folder first (say, on first run) and then read / write to that one subsequently. There are plenty of questions dealing with how to do this, for example : [copying plist to document directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693364/copying-plist-to-document-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSDictionary for key-value coding:

```
// create dictionary
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
// add it to plist
[plist setObject:dict forKey:@"customDictionary"];
```